# How can you make an if statement that checks if input is a str/int

Tags: python, string, if-statement, input, integer

basically im new to python programming and I've just learnt about user input. Im trying to make an if statement that checks if the input is a str or int and then prints a message. If anyone knows how then please comment it, thanks.

```
print("How old are you?")
dog = input()
final = int(dog) + int(100)

if dog == str:
    print("No")
else:
    print("\nHeres you name + 100!")
    print(f"{final}")
    print("Thanks for playing!")
```

btw the if statement that I put doesn't work, I dont know if I need to put an exception so it responds with not an error message.

Comment: `input()` **always** returns a `str`.

Answer (score 3):

Re how to check types, you can do like this:

```py
my_string = "hello"
if isinstance(my_string, str):
    print("I'm a string")
else:
    print("I'm not")

# outputs: "I'm a string"
```

However, as commented the input method is always returning a value of type str. So if you want to ensure that the value is only consisting of numerical characters, you can use the string method `isdigit()`

```py
my_string = "asd"
my_string.isdigit() # returns False
my_string = "123"
my_string.isdigit() # returns True
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `type` method to check:

```
print("How old are you?")
dog = input()
final = int(dog) + int(100)

#use type method to check the type of the variable
if type(dog) == str:
    print("No")
else:
    print("\nHeres you name + 100!")
    print(f"{final}")
    print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Another thing you can do is set prevent the user from entering anything but an `int` and force a proper variable, something like:

```
while True:
  dog = input('How old are you? ')
  try:
    dog = int(dog)
    break
  except ValueError:
      print('No')

final = dog + 100
print("\nHeres you name + 100!")
print(f"{final}")
print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Also, don't waste processing power by converting an `int` to an `int` so that means `int(100)` is the same as `100`